# Java printing ArrayList of points

Tags: java, image, arraylist, tostring

How would I go about printing an arraylist full of points generated by the ImageIO.read method?
This doesn't seem to work for me :(

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {   
    System.out.println(deepToString(list.get(i)));
}
```

Comment: How doesn't it work? How does the list get populated?

Comment: `ImageIO.read(...)` returns a `BufferedImage`. That class has nothing to do with points, unless you are showing Paul Cézanne paintings. It certainly is not an array of any sort, and `deepToString` is a method on `Arrays`.

Comment: Given information is not sufficient to answer the question.

Comment: What else should I include? All I want to do is print a list of all the <Point>'s in an ArrayList. What else is there to say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ImageIO.read()` returns only `BufferedImage`. Where from did you get the `List<Point>`?
Assuming you are getting `List<Point>` from some where, the following should work.

```
    List<Point> list = ...;

    for (Point p : list)
        System.out.println(p);
```

If your objective is to print all the colors in the given image with its x, y, then use the following code...

```
    BufferedImage im = ImageIO.read(....);

    int width = im.getWidth();
    int height = im.getHeight();

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            System.out.println("x = " + x + ", y = " + y + ", color = " + im.getRGB(x, y));
    }
```

If none of these satisfy your need, pls explain your need correctly...